PDFTable usando ItexSharp: espacio en blanco en la tabla con muchos elementos
Necesito de su ayuda, ya que he probado varias cosas pero no he podido solucionar un problema que tengo, tengo un RECIBO que tiene muchos documentos, y cuando esto pasa la tabla que genera el PDF genera un espacio en blanco grande y comienza en una nueva hoja.
Como en el siguiente ejemplo:
ingrese la descripción de la imagen aquí
Para llenar la tabla uso la siguiente fragmento de código.
`PdfPTable tablaGral = new PdfPTable(1);
        PdfPTable tablaItems = new PdfPTable(9);
        float[] widths2 = new float[] { 90f, 40f, 50f, 50f, 60f, 60f, 60f, 50f, 50f };
        tablaItems.SetWidths(widths2);

        PdfPCell pdfCellTipoComprobate = AgregarCelda("Tipo Comprobante", FontEncabezados6, 0, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, true);
        pdfCellTipoComprobate.BorderWidthTop = 0f;
        pdfCellTipoComprobate.BorderWidthLeft = 0f;
        pdfCellTipoComprobate.BorderWidthBottom = 0.5f;

        tablaItems.AddCell(pdfCellTipoComprobate);

        tablaItems.AddCell(AgregarCelda("Pto. Venta", FontEncabezados6, 0, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, false));
        tablaItems.AddCell(AgregarCelda("Nro", FontEncabezados6, 0, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, false));
        tablaItems.AddCell(AgregarCelda("Fecha", FontEncabezados6, 0, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, false));
        tablaItems.AddCell(AgregarCelda("Total", FontEncabezados6, 0, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, false));
        tablaItems.AddCell(AgregarCelda("Monto Aplicado", FontEncabezados6, 0, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, false));
        tablaItems.AddCell(AgregarCelda("Saldo", FontEncabezados6, 0, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, false));
        tablaItems.AddCell(AgregarCelda("Moneda", FontEncabezados6, 0, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, false));
        PdfPCell pdfCellPTotal = AgregarCelda("Cotizacion", FontEncabezados6, 0, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, true);
        pdfCellPTotal.BorderWidthTop = 0f;
        pdfCellPTotal.BorderWidthBottom = 0.5f;
        pdfCellPTotal.BorderWidthRight = 0f;
        tablaItems.AddCell(pdfCellPTotal);


        int contador = 0;
        int cantidad = lstReciboFactura.Count;
        foreach (ReciboFactura rf in lstReciboFactura)
        {

            

            string tipoDocumento = rf.TipoComprobanteNombre;
            PdfPCell pdfCellTipoComprobanteValue = AgregarCelda(tipoDocumento, FontDetalle6, 0, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, true);
            pdfCellTipoComprobanteValue.BorderWidthLeft = 0f;
            pdfCellTipoComprobanteValue.BorderWidthRight = 0f;

            tablaItems.AddCell(pdfCellTipoComprobanteValue);

            string ptoVenta = rf.PtoVenta == 0 ? "" : rf.PtoVenta.ToString("0000");
            PdfPCell pdfCellPtoVentaValue = AgregarCelda(ptoVenta, FontDetalle6, 0, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, true);

            pdfCellPtoVentaValue.BorderWidthRight = 0f;
            tablaItems.AddCell(pdfCellPtoVentaValue);

            PdfPCell pdfCellNroValue = AgregarCelda(rf.NroComprobante.ToString("000000000"), FontDetalle6, 0, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, true);
            pdfCellNroValue.BorderWidthRight = 0f;
            tablaItems.AddCell(pdfCellNroValue);

            PdfPCell pdfCellPUnitarionValue = AgregarCelda(rf.FechaStr, FontDetalle6, 0, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, true);
            pdfCellPUnitarionValue.BorderWidthRight = 0f;
            tablaItems.AddCell(pdfCellPUnitarionValue);

            PdfPCell pdfCellPUnitarionGravadoValue = AgregarCelda((rf.Importe).ToString("0,0.00"), FontDetalle6, 0, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, true);
            pdfCellPUnitarionGravadoValue.BorderWidthRight = 0f;
            tablaItems.AddCell(pdfCellPUnitarionGravadoValue);

            PdfPCell pdfCellPUnitarionNoGravadoValue = AgregarCelda(rf.MontoAplicado.ToString("0,0.00"), FontDetalle6, 0, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, true);
            pdfCellPUnitarionNoGravadoValue.BorderWidthRight = 0f;
            tablaItems.AddCell(pdfCellPUnitarionNoGravadoValue);


            PdfPCell pdfCellSaldoFacturaValue = AgregarCelda(rf.SaldoFactura.ToString("0,0.00"), FontDetalle6, 0, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, true);
            pdfCellSaldoFacturaValue.BorderWidthRight = 0f;
            tablaItems.AddCell(pdfCellSaldoFacturaValue);

            PdfPCell pdfCellMonedaValue = AgregarCelda(rf.MonedaStr, FontDetalle6, 0, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, true);
            pdfCellMonedaValue.BorderWidthRight = 0f;
            tablaItems.AddCell(pdfCellMonedaValue);

            string cotizacion = rf.MonedaId == 4 ? "1" : rf.Cotizacion.ToString("0,0.00");
            PdfPCell pdfCellCotizacionValue = AgregarCelda(cotizacion, FontDetalle6, 0, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, true);
            pdfCellCotizacionValue.BorderWidthRight = 0f;
            tablaItems.AddCell(pdfCellCotizacionValue);

            contador++;

            if (contador == 30 || contador == cantidad) //Se usa para hacer una linea cada 30 comprobantes.

            {
                PdfPCell celdaTable2 = new PdfPCell(tablaItems);
                tablaGral.AddCell(celdaTable2);

                tablaItems.DeleteBodyRows();

                contador = 0;
            }

            
            }

        PdfPCell celdaGral2 = new PdfPCell(tablaGral);
        celdaGral2.MinimumHeight = 300f;// : 440f;
        table.AddCell(celdaGral2);

`
Todas las pruebas que se hicieron fueron recortando la cantidad de registros del recibo y se imprime correctamente, si la cantidad de registros es menos a 45.

Has usado tabla.setKeepTogether(false) ? https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/java/5.5.12/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#setKeepTogether-boolean- Además, revisa el margin de la tabla anterior de la que pusiste el código

@javdromero
Mi código está en C#, pero he usado tablaGral.KeepTogether= false; pero me sucede lo mismo.
`PdfPTable tablaGral = new PdfPTable(1);
        tablaGral.TotalWidth = 552f;
        tablaGral.LockedWidth = true;
        
        tablaGral.KeepTogether= false;

        float[] widths = new float[] { 552f };
        tablaGral.SetWidths(widths);`

